# php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth login error

Tags: php, jwt, tymon-jwt

i get the following error when i try to login and i don't find where the problem is. I use lumen 9 with php 8.1.

```
<!-- Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder::relatedTo(): Argument #1 ($subject) must be of type string, null given, called in /home/ss20nt22/public_html/wms/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/Providers/JWT/Lcobucci.php on line 212 (500 Internal Server Error) -->
```

here is my function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nume' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only(['nume', 'password']);
        if (!$token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Login has failed
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
```

Comment: It's happening to me too in Laravel 8.
This started 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows, I uninstalled the package and installed it again from the documentation here.

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

In the case of lumen, do the same procedure with the documentation below.

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/lumen-installation/

Steps:

uninstall the package

Remove JWT_SECRET from .env or elsewhere

If possible remove the file

config/jwt.php

Clear all lumen cache

Stop the web service

Follow the installation instructions in the link

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/lumen-installation/

Recalling that I use Laravel 8 in php 8

Comment: Please list steps you followed to fix this issue and then references.

Comment: not working, i have it configured as it should, still not working.

Comment: same also not working for me

Comment: I have some same kind of problem, what I have do is add config/jwt.php file on it,

Answer (score 2):

If anyone have same problems in laravel 9 and above, but have sure JWT_SECRET is exist in .env file your problem can be in primary key id is not same between migrations and models.

when you have migration with custom id name like this :

```
 $table->id('user_id');
```

then register it in User Model like this:

```
protected $primaryKey = "user_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

In config\jwt.php file Change

> 'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci::class,
> to
> 'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running `php artisan config:cache`. This command caches your configuration. This helped me, as I noticed that environment variables sometimes do not have time to be loaded into the dynamic config.

And just in case, make sure that you generated secret key by running `php artisan jwt:secret`